# Slider value not updating Bokeh Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, slider, bokeh, interactive

I am having struggles with making an interactive plot in Jupyter Notebook with the use of Bokeh. I want to plot a map of the world and display the development of some data over time. I succeeded in making a plot and having a slider to adjust the year, but as I change the slider, the slider value won't update. The code for the slider is below:

```
#creating the data source as a dict
source = ColumnDataSource({
    'x': p_df['x'], 
    'y': p_df['y'], 
    'Country': p_df['Country'], 
    'nkill': p_df['nkill']
})

#making a slider and assign the update_plot function to changes
slider = Slider(start=start_yr, end=end_yr, step=1, value=start_yr, title='Year')
slider.on_change('value',update_plot)

#the update_plot function which needs to run based on the new slider.value
def update_plot(attr, old, new):
    #Update glyph locations
    yr = slider.value
    Amountkills_dt_year = p_df[p_df['Year'] ==yr]
    new_data = {
        'x': Amountkills_dt_year['x'], 
        'y': Amountkills_dt_year['y'], 
        'Country': Amountkills_dt_year['Country'], 
        'nkill': Amountkills_dt_year['nkill']
    }
    source.data = new_data
    #Update colors
    color_mapper = LinearColorMapper(palette='Viridis256',
                                 low = min(Amount_of_Terrorist_Attacks['nkill']),
                                 high = max(Amount_of_Terrorist_Attacks['nkill']))
```

Where I want to update the plot with the update_plot() function. I tried the solution in [Python bokeh slider not refreshing plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54628954/python-bokeh-slider-not-refreshing-plot) but I still encoutered the same error.

Comment: Are you running this as a Bokeh server application, i.e. with `bokeh serve app.py`?

Comment: No, I am running my app in jupyter notebook and plotting my map with `show()`, I guessed maybe using `show()` makes a static plot instead of a plot which can interact with my slider...

Answer (score 0):

Bokeh widgets like sliders don't work in jupyter notebooks (at least, not without using some javascript).  As the [documentation](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/widgets.html) says:

```
To use widgets, you must add them to your document and define their functionality. Widgets can be added directly to the document root or nested inside a layout. There are two ways to program a widget’s functionality:

        Use the CustomJS callback (see JavaScript Callbacks). This will work in standalone HTML documents.

        Use bokeh serve to start the Bokeh server and set up event handlers with .on_change (or for some widgets, .on_click).
```

As @bigreddot hints,  you will need to use the bokeh server or else
perhaps some of the features in the discussion of jupyter interactors that are discussed [here](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/jupyter.html#userguide-jupyter-notebook).

Comment: Bokeh widgets and Bokeh server apps can be used in notebooks but you have to do things a specific way. See the notebook_embed.ipynb example in the repo.