# Selecting K in Python and Bokeh; slider widget not updating Python code

Tags: python, widget, data-visualization, bokeh, k-means

I am trying to create a clustering function using Python and interacting it using a slider widget on Bokeh. The slider widget allows the user to select the value of K (i.e. number of clusters to find).

Here is a sample of the code:-

```
from bokeh.models.annotations import Label
import numpy as np
from sklearn import cluster, datasets
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

from bokeh.layouts import column, row
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, Select, Slider
from bokeh.io import curdoc
print("\n\n*** This example may take several seconds to run before displaying. ***\n\n")

N = 50000
PLOT_SIZE = 400

# generate datasets.
np.random.seed(0)
noisy_circles = datasets.make_circles(n_samples=N, factor=.5, noise=.04)
noisy_moons = datasets.make_moons(n_samples=N, noise=.05)
centers = [(-2, 3), (2, 3), (-2, -3), (2, -3)]
blobs1 = datasets.make_blobs(centers=centers, n_samples=N, cluster_std=0.4, random_state=8)
blobs2 = datasets.make_blobs(centers=centers, n_samples=N, cluster_std=0.7, random_state=8)

colors = np.array([x for x in ('#00f', '#0f0', '#f00', '#0ff', '#f0f', '#ff0')])
colors = np.hstack([colors] * 20)




k_slider = Slider(title = "Select K", value=3, start = 2, end = 6)

k = k_slider.value

kmeans   = cluster.KMeans(n_clusters= k)

def update_k(attr,old,new):
    k = k_slider.value
    kmeans   = cluster.KMeans(n_clusters= k)
    return kmeans

k_slider.on_change('value', update_k)

algorithm = kmeans



plots =[]
for dataset in (noisy_circles, noisy_moons, blobs1, blobs2):
    X, y = dataset
    X = StandardScaler().fit_transform(X)

    algorithm.fit(X)
    if hasattr(algorithm, 'labels_'):
        y_pred = algorithm.labels_.astype(int)
    else:
        y_pred = algorithm.predict(X)
    p = figure(output_backend="webgl", title=algorithm.__class__.__name__,width=PLOT_SIZE, height=PLOT_SIZE)
    p.circle(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], color=colors[y_pred].tolist(), alpha=0.1,)
    plots.append(p)




layout = column(k_slider,row(plots[:2]), row(plots[2:]))

output_file("clustering.html", title="clustering with sklearn")

curdoc().add_root(layout)
```

The default value of K is 3 but I want the slider widget to change this to anything between 2-6. I launch this app with bokeh serve and it brings up the plots with 3 clusters visualised. However, it is not allowing me to update the plot when I change the slider.

I have consulted the following:-

[Slider value not updating Bokeh Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60713879/slider-value-not-updating-bokeh-python)

[Running a Bokeh server](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html)

But the solution to my issue isn't obvious.
Can anyone tell me/add in what what I am missing with my code?

Many thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Updating a Bokeh figure means updating the `data_source` of it's renderer, in this case the `circle`. So you **would** need to do smth like:

`plots[0].renderers[0].data_source.data['x'] = NEW_X[:, 0]`
`plots[0].renderers[0].data_source.data['y'] = NEW_X[:, 1]`
`plots[0].renderers[0].data_source.change.emit()`

and the same for `colors`...

2. It looks like you need to repeat your entire `for` loop in your Python callback as `algorithm` is the `kmeans` which depends on `K`. And if your `K` means number of clusters and every cluster is represented by one plot it means you need to remove/add plots dynamically dependent on `K`.
3. So if 2) is true you don't need to update existing plots in your callback but you could try alternatively to just remove the existing `root` and add a new one containing the new plots. So in your callback you could do:

> 

```
def update_k(attr,old,new):
    k = k_slider.value
    kmeans   = cluster.KMeans(n_clusters= k)
    
    plots =[]
    for dataset in (noisy_circles, noisy_moons, blobs1, blobs2):
        ...
        plots.append(p)

    curdoc().remove_root()
    curdoc().add_root(column(k_slider,row(plots[:2]), row(plots[2:])))
```

It should work but to be sure consult the docs on how to use [remove_root()](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/document.html)

Alternatively instead of removing root you could manipulate/replace the `layout.children` which are [`k_slider, row1, row2]`